# How can I render a theme partial from within a component

Tags: themes, octobercms, renderpartial

I want to reuse a modal partial between several plugins and components.  Depending on the Bootstrap version supplied with a theme, the modal may have different properties so I have decided to create a modal in each theme to use site wide.  When I change a theme I just add appropriately coded partial in the theme.

Then my component can just render the modal when needed with needed variables.

My solution will be like:

```
 public function modalSet($sections) {
        $modal_path = $this->getTheme()->getPath() . '/partials/site/modal.htm';

        return ['#modal' => $this->renderPartial($modal_path,
            [
                'title' => array_get($sections, 'title', ''),
                'subhead' => array_get($sections, 'subhead', ''),
                'body' => array_get($sections, 'body', ''),
                'foot' => array_get($sections, 'foot', ''),
            ]),
        ];
    }


    onShowInfo(){
        return $this->modalSet([
                'title' => 'Information About The Thing',
                'body' => '<p>The thing is really Big</p>',
        ]);
    }
```

The problem is that $this->renderPartial tries to find a partial in the component instead of the theme even if I pass the whole theme partial path.

I get Error: " The page '/home/kurt/public_html/mysite/themes/mytheme/partials/site/modal.htm' is not found"

So what do I need to do in order to render a Theme partial from inside a component?

Comment: Have you implemented this type of modal [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) ? And do you want to use that into all components and plugins?

Comment: I am using this in one specific site that has my own private plugins. All forms are AJAX and use the modal. The site is data intesive with multiple companies tracking there own equipment data through front end. I am also using a custom behavior that takes care of repetitive CRUD for all components. Breaking the individual equipment types into their own plugins makes each equipment piece more manageable.  Common CRUD with this modal method will make it easier for me to change themes in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little difference in `theme partials` they are `acting differently from regular partials`. they are kind of `Halcyon Model` // little off topic

ok, here is the way to do it.

> just use name with directory **[** make sure you use `.htm` extension for your partial files its needed. and site folder must be inside `partials folder` **]**

```
    // use this path it will respect current active theme
    // and pick partial from active theme automatically 

    $modal_path = 'site/modal.htm'; 
    return ['#modal' => $this->renderPartial($modal_path,
        [
            'title' => array_get($sections, 'title', ''),
            'subhead' => array_get($sections, 'subhead', ''),
            'body' => array_get($sections, 'body', ''),
            'foot' => array_get($sections, 'foot', ''),
        ]),
    ];
```

it will do trick and load partial from the directory and give you `desired html`

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: I was making this way more complicated than I needed to by thinking I needed to get the full path for the partial.
Thanks @hardik_satasiya

Comment: Excellent answer Hardik.